# How to Add attachments from "Default Mail App" to "MyApp" in iOS programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I add attachments from "Default Mail App" to "MyApp" in iOS programmatically? what are the possible ways to achieve this?

My scenario is :

1. Long press on Attachment which is there in "Mail App"
2. Activity Controller Appears
3. Should Get saved in "My App"

If saved how to access the same file in "My App"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS each application belongs to it's own island called sandbox, And you can only access those documents that are present in the sandbox of your application.

So to allow user to attach a document you first need to share that particular attachment or use open in MyApp to save it in the sandbox of your application.

You can do that very easily in your

```
info.plist
```

file you need to set the keys like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYH5z.png

This specifies that your application supports opening pdf hence when you long press on the attachment you will get a option to open in MyApp as well

Once you click open in you will receive the file URL in your AppDelegate function

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

Now you can perform appropriate action in this function and save the file in your sandbox then you can attach it from MyApp

```
[Filestorage instance]
```

get the instance and extract the list of files in your directory.